# Meteor: issue with reactivity in the #each loop

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post images, so that makes it a bit harder to show the issue at hand. So I will describe it here.
In my final Meteor on screen display, I have an invoice with line-items. The line-items and all work perfectly and show as expected.
What I wanted to do, was "break in" in the #each-loop after 4 line-items are printed on screen, and then do something else (calculate and print sub-totals). I can't get that to work, since the session var I created for that does not seem to reactively change on every line-item. Instead, it seems to hold the last value from the complete #each loop.

Note, that there is a listindex variable in there that perfectly re-actively builds up from 1, to 2,3, and 4 on each line-item that is within the #each loop. So, the listindex variable **does** work reactively within the #each loop.

At the same time, I am introducing a session var in there, that should be "true" on line-item number 4, and "false" in all other cases. On "true" it should print "onderbreking" right in there. However, the session var **always** gives "true" and (because of that) **always** prints "onderbreking". That's not how I intended it to work of course.

I do not understand why the listindex works, and the session var does not?

Here is my javascript on this. The template is called "layout6.html":

```
  Template.layout6.helpers({
        // Bereken de index in de #each loop
        listIndex: function() {
          currentIndex += 1;
          if(currentIndex == 4) {
            Session.set('sessionPageBreak1', true);
          }
          if(currentIndex != 4) {
            Session.set('sessionPageBreak1', false);
          }
        return currentIndex;
        },            
  });    

 Template.layout6.SessionPageBreak1 = function() {
            // Voeg de waarde van de sessie variabele toe aan de template
            var data = Session.get('sessionPageBreak1');
            return data;
 };
```

The session var is initially set here:

```
  // Session var for layoutcounter
  Session.setDefault('sessionPageBreak1', false);
  Session.setDefault('sessionPageBreak2', false); 
  Session.setDefault('sessionPageBreak3', false);  
  var currentIndex = 0.0;
```

Finally, this is the html involved on layout6.html:

```
{{#each factuur6.lineItems}}
  {{listIndex}}
  {{SessionPageBreak1}}
{{#if SessionPageBreak1}}
<div><p>onderbreking</p></div>
{{/if}}
```

And of course, there is a {{/each}} statement as well, but there is a lot of code in between that is not very relevant for this issue, so I did not put it in here.

I hope I included everything, if not, you guys doubtlessly will tell me.

The question is: what am I doing wrong, so that the session var is not reactively changing within the #each loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really the right way to use Session variables. Session variables are for global application state, not for storing intermediate values through a single computation. The general rule is that templates and template helpers should not have side-effects (like setting Session variables).

I would take a different approach. Define a helper:

```js
lineItemsWithIndex: function () {
  return _.map(this.factuur6.lineItems, function (item, index) {
    var newItem = _.clone(item);
    newItem.index = index;
    return newItem;
  });
}
```

This function returns a copy of `this.factuur6.lineItems`, except each object has an `index` property added to it. For example, if the list of `lineItems` is `[{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "baz"}]`, we return `[{name: "foo", index: 0}, {name: "bar", index: 1}, {name: "baz", index: 2}]`. The original list is unchanged. If `factuur6` is a helper rather than a field, then instead use `_.map(Template.layout6.factuur6().lineItems ...`.

Then iterate over that in your template:

```html
{{#each lineItemsWithIndex}}
  {{index}}
  {{pageBreak1}}
  {{#if pageBreak1}}
    <div><p>onderbreking</p></div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Where `pageBreak1` is a helper `function () {return this.index == 3;}` (3 rather than 4, since these indices are 0-based). Since we added the index to each object, it is now accessible in the helper.

This assumes that your line items don't already have a field called `index`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response ! I am grateful for any help. But I am having trouble understanding what you exactly are doing in your functions. If possible, could you elaborate a bit more on what exactly is happening within those functions?

Comment: I implemented your code just as is, and now no lineItems at all are showing. Obviously, you expect me to adjust something in my code outside of what you stated above, that I did not pick up on :-) sorry for that.... can you assist?

Comment: Also, I just noticed, {{#each listItemsWithIndex}} seems to have a typo, should probably be: {{#each lineItemsWithIndex}} ?

Comment: I'm not sure what `factuur6` is, I guessed it was a field but if it was a helper than you'll have to call it instead, see my edit.

Comment: Factuur6 indeed is a helper, defined as follows:
      Template.layout6.factuur6 = function(){
          return Factuurlijst.findOne({_id:Session.get('factuurid')});
      }

Comment: It WORKS. This is really great. Now, with the added explanation, I can go and study what you created here. Thank you very much for helping me out, and taking the extra effort to explain it to me. I appreciate it very much !!